# How does YouTube's flash player retrieve its media?

Tags: flash, architecture, soap, youtube

I'm trying to build a flash widget which will grab videos stored on my server. How does one do this to allow for maximum scalability?

I want to emulate what YouTube does.

Does it make a SOAP request? What kind of server is it talking to? An application server? A server that only serves videos?

Answer (score 0):

The players request misc. data from the yt servers using either XML or LoadVars, and the videos are generally just flv or mp4 files that are served from web servers, as stated in the article:

> Servers use the lighttpd web server for video:
>
> - Apache had too much overhead.